# How do i know if i'm disconnected from a Dart websocket server

Tags: websocket, dart

I created a WebSocket server, and it works just fine, however, i don't know how to detect if a client is disconnected, can anyone help me ?

here is my code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
const port=8080;
List users=new List();

void main() {

  HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', port)
    .then((HttpServer server)=>
      server.listen((HttpRequest request) =>

          WebSocketTransformer.upgrade(request).then((WebSocket websocket) {
            //what can i do here to detect if my websocket is closed
            users.add(websocket);
            websocket.add("clients Number is ${users.length}");
          })
      )
   );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since a `WebSocket` is a `Stream` it will close when the socket is disconnected. This is a nice property of many of the dart:io classes implementing Stream - you can interact with them al lthe same way, once you know how to use Streams.

You can detect when a Stream closes in several ways:

1. Add an `onDone` handler to your `listen()` call:

   ```
   websocket.listen(handler, onDone: doneHandler);
   ```
2. Add an on-done handler to the `StreamSubscription` returned from `listen()`:

   ```
   var sub = websocket.listen(handler);
   sub.onDone(doneHandler);
   ```
3. Turn the `StreamSubscription` into a `Future` via `asFuture()` and wait for it to complete:

   ```
   var sub = websocket.listen(handler);
   sub.asFuture().then((_) => doneHandler);
   ```

Comment: you're awesome!(i bet i'm not the first one who tells you this :D)thanks dude!